# Void * to char or int in C

Tags: c, int, malloc, structure, void-pointers

I want to get any types of variables in my code, so I did a void * type to accept others. But I can get in char * but not in int values. And I don't understand how I can did it.
Here my code :

```
void    insertion(t_liste *liste, void *newValue) {
  t_element *new = malloc(sizeof(void *));
  int i;
  int *j = &i;

  if (liste == NULL || new == NULL) {
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  if (newValue == j || (char *)newValue) {
     new->value = newValue;
     new->suivant = liste->premier;
     liste->premier = new;
     liste->taille++;
     new->index = liste->taille;
  }
}
```

In my main I did

```
insertion(maListe, 5);
```

it didn't work, but if I did this:

```
insertion(maListe, "test");
```

It works.
But I want both works !
Here my .h

```
typedef struct s_element t_element;
typedef struct s_liste t_liste;

struct s_element{
  int           index;
  void          *value;
  t_element     *suivant;
  t_element     *precedent;
};

struct s_liste{
  t_element     *premier;
  t_element     *dernier;
  int           taille;
};
```

Any idea ?

Comment: Using `new` as a variable name is not a good idea

Comment: @EdHeal it's a great idea, means idiots who think "use a c++ compiler to compile c code" is a good idea, actually end up wasting their time

Comment: `void *` is a pointer to any type. `5` is not a pointer but a number. Numbers are no pointers.

Comment: Gerhardh is right what you want to achieve is insert a pointer in your list not a number itself.

Comment: 1) `t_element *new = malloc(sizeof(void *));` --> `t_element *new = malloc(sizeof(*new));` or `t_element *new = malloc(sizeof(t_element));`

Comment: Yes but I want to send any type of things, did you mean I have to put insertion(maListe, "5"); ? Yes for malloc I was testing some ideas it was t_element *new = malloc(sizeof(*new)); before ^^

Comment: No, @MorganeFlamant. You can't send "5".

Comment: It's impossible to send int type in void* ?

Comment: int value = 5; insertion(maListe,(void*)&value);

Comment: Ok, I have to transform it before I send it

Comment: But you have to think twice before doing that, because maybe when you insert the item you know what type it is, but when you traverse the list it you lose that info, because of that you need to create a system by which you store the type of item you insert in your list

Comment: Ok thank you, I will be careful with this !

Comment: This is not an unreasonable question. @Cristian, want to make your comment a full answer? Bonus points for advice on the type problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK! In your function
`void    insertion(t_liste *liste, void *newValue)`
 you are taking a argument of type void* . In the first case when you send a string(char *) the base address of the string is passed , so address is taken to `newValue`,but in case when you pass a number,say 5 ,integer is passed to `newValue` where it expects an address.